# Automated email sender using excel data

Tags: perl, excel, outlook

I would like an automated email sender for birthdays. This is what I would like to accomplish:

- Check Today's Date
- Find match in Column 'DOB'
- If true, get data from corresponding columns 'Name' and 'Email' (Might have to use for each)
- Create Outlook Email with Subject 'Happy Birthday'
- Message text – Dear $Name, Happy Birthday!
- Send Email

After a bit of research I understand I will have to use the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and one of the Outlook modules (not sure which one).

Comment: Since you want to read the excel file, Spreadsheet::Read seems more apt.

Comment: Don't bother with outlook, take a look at MIME::Lite.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is all stuff that you can find out on your own. Once you've *really* tried to implement this yourself, you might find you don't even need help. Which is really beneficial to your learning. However, if you do find you're having trouble once you've really gave it a good go. Then come back here and ask a question.

Comment: You will probably not get snippets of code here, unless you already show us some code of your own, first. Take a look at the [faq#howtoask] if you want to know more about that.

Comment: @innaM Thanks, looks promising. Will get back if I get stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

get today's date with the help of system.getDate() after that fetch date of birth from database match both the date if matched send sms. for sending sms use mail.cs function and write body of mail.